# Error : The website declined to show this webpage SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Sometimes my user gets following error when opens SharePoint site but when he clicks browser back button error disappears and site loads fine.

[image]

User has full control on the site and strange I don't get this error at my end.

Comment: Use fiddler2 on the client computer, together with the ULS logs to try to get down to what it is that throws the error. It could very well be a masterpage or page layout not being checked in.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLindgren. I will have a try as you suggested.

Comment: Do have Anonymous login settings set for your Authentication Zones in Central Admin? Or you can set anonymous in IIS settings